# Difference between jquery form submission and remote form submission in Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have seen some of applications, In ajax requests are two types

1. `link_to :remote =>true` like ........
2. `$(ajax).save` button click function .......

What is the difference between those? Which one is the best approach for rails?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what exactly you want to know, but the first one is the new way to handle Ajax requests since Rails 3. Up from this version, Unobstrusive JavaScript (UJS) was integrated in Rails. After creating a new Rails 3 app, a JavaScript file rails.js is used. Imho, you should use the first one since this is the Rails way.

The second one is - as far as I understand - the plain jQuery implementation. This is also a possible way but you have to implement more functionality by yourself.

Here is a good article about UJS: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/

Here is a very good (revised) railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised